# Struct comparison

Tags: c, struct, comparison, pebble-watch

I am working on a project for the Pebble platform. Apps are written in C, and my question is not specific to that platform.

The Pebble API has a Struct called [PblTm](https://developer.getpebble.com/sdkref/group___wall_time.html#struct_pbl_tm) that is populated every second by a line of code. My goal is to compare the struct with the current time. I have created PblTm structs and populated them with the times I need to compare against. I only care about the hour and minute sections of the structs. So far, I have the following code.

```
bool comp_time(int h1, int m1, int h2, int m2, int h3, int m3) {

    if((h1<=h2)  && (h2<=h3)) //Is start hour <= now hour <= end hour?
    {
        if((h1=h2) && (m2>=m1)) //If start hour = now hour, is now min >= start min ?
        {
            return true; 
        }
        if((h2=h3) && (m2<=m3)) //If end hour = now hour, if now min <= end min?
        {
            return true;
        }
        if((h1>h2) && (h2<h3)) //If start hour < now hour < end hour?
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;

}
```

I initially tried to feed the structs themselves as parameter to the function something like:

```
comp_time(&first_start,&now,&first_end);
```

And then referenced the elements of the struct inside the function, I could never get that to compile, and I couldn't find information on it. (I may have not have been searching for the correct terms).

I then changed to feeding the int parameters to the function itself like this:

```
comp_time(first_start.tm_hour,first_start.tm_min,now.tm_hour,now.tm_min,first_end.tm_hour,first_end.tm_min)
```

It is a quite clumsy way of doing it, but I have already done the work to type it all out. My main problem however, is that the comparison function doesn't function. It returns (apparently randomly, I have not been able to find a pattern) true for values that do not fit and false for some that fit.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Your comparison isn't working because you're using single equals `=` instead of double equals `==` to check for equality. It'll take an actual answer to explain why your function call isn't working.

Comment: @Xymostech Thanks! I have no I idea how I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so your parameter names make it very difficult to read the code and reason about it, so lets rewrite it a bit:

```
bool comp_time(int hstart, int mstart, int hnow, int mnow, int hend, int mend) {
  if (( hstart <= hnow ) && ( hnow <= hend ))
  {
```

So far so good.  We know that if `hnow` is less than `hstart` or more than `hend` then it can't be true.

```
if((hstart==hnow) && (mnow>=mstart)) return true ;  // BAD
```

Besides the fix for `==` instead of `=`, this is still wrong.  You're only testing one side of the boundary.  You need to test against both `start` and `end` to make sure you're inside the range:

```
if ( ( (hstart < hnow ) || (mstart <= mnow ) ) &&
    ( (hnow < hend) || (mnow <= mend ) ) )  { return true ; }
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. With that last block of code, I must admit that I don't fully understand what is going on, but it does work, I wrote a quick program to check it outside of all the complexity of the rest of the app. It seems like we have already tested that the hour falls in between our values and why is mnow <= to both mstart and mend?

Answer (score 2):

You should really update to Pebble SDK2 which provides a `time_t` value for time. This value is a timestamp ([number of seconds since epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) and you can easily compare it in one operation.

Comment: I thought about that, but despite having to rewrite my app, I am not sure that, because I only need to compare within one day, how I would handle dynamically updating the number of seconds since epoch each day.

Comment: int seconds_since_midnight = tm.tm_hour * 3600 + tm.tm_min * 60 + tm.tm_sec;